# Unstoppable loop

Tags: javascript, php

I improved the question by adding my code.

I’m stuck on making an unstoppable loop please help me.

I’m calling 5 api url:

Each url should be called on a specific number:

```
URL1 should be called 4 times
URL2 should be called 10 times
URL3 should be called 8 times
URL4 should be called 9 times
URL5 should be called 6 times
```

Please have a look at my code below:
https://www.codepile.net/pile/7Plo91MN

The loop should start from URL1 and when it reaches URL5 then it should again start from URL1 it should be unstoppable.

Comment: Code example perhaps? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What if you needed to call each URL just 1 time? Can you handle such case?

Comment: Are the calls asynchronous?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you will need to add your URL calling code tho.

```js
let arrUrls = [
  ["URL1", 4],
  ["URL2", 10],
  ["URL3", 8],
  ["URL4", 9],
  ["URL5", 6]
];

let sendNum = 0;

function callUrl(url, rpt){
  for (let i = 0; i < rpt; i++) {
    // calling code
    console.log(`called ${url} - ${i}/${sendNum}`);
  }
};

let x = 0;
while(x<4) // Change this to while(true) for infinite loop
{
  sendNum = 0;
  arrUrls.forEach(u => {
    sendNum++;
    callUrl(u[0], u[1]);
  });
  x++;
}
```

As per comments from guest. This is a more UI friendly version. Also I added a 3sec sleep and a stop button for convenience.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if(interval !== undefined) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    console.log('Stopped !!');
  }
});

let arrUrls = [
  ["URL1", 4],
  ["URL2", 10],
  ["URL3", 8],
  ["URL4", 9],
  ["URL5", 6]
];

let sendNum = 0;
let interval = undefined;

function callUrl(url, rpt) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rpt; i++) {
    // calling code
    count++;
  }    
  console.log(`called ${url} - ${count} times - on loop: ${sendNum}`);
};


interval = setInterval(() => // Change this to while(true) for infinite loop
{
  console.clear();
  sendNum++;
  arrUrls.forEach(u => {
    callUrl(u[0], u[1]);
  });
}, 3000);
```

```html
<button>Stop Me</button>
```

Comment: The code at the answer has a bug.

Comment: Is there? I ran it on limited loops and it seemed to work.

Comment: Does the browser tab freeze at any point during the process? Particularly `console`?

Comment: Its because it was written as infinite and that wont work here.

Comment: But this would work fine on a service worker for example. I edited so that people can try it.

Comment: Infinite loops do not necessarily have to freeze the browser or spin the HD. How is  `ServiceWorker` related to the question?

Comment: @guest271314 more than fair, it could be done with an interval call. Would be more friendly then.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use an `InfiniteIterator`. Surprisingly enough, it iterates infinitely.

```
$urls = ['url1' => 4, 'url2' => 10, 'url3' => 8, 'url4'=> 9, 'url5' => 6];

$unstoppable = new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($urls));

foreach ($unstoppable as $url => $times) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $times; $i++) {
        // call $url
    }
}
```

You'll be banned from each of those URLs before you know it!